# How to prove that every maximal outerplanar graph has exactly 2n-3 edges without induction？

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

I recently saw such an interesting theorem.

> Every maximal outerplanar graph has exactly 2n-3 edges.

A similar question is here [Every maximal outerplanar graph has exactly 2n-3 edges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3875768/every-maximal-outerplanar-graph-has-exactly-2n-3-edges).

I have seen that many textbooks basically use induction, provided that there must be a 2-degree vertex. This is very good, but I feel that there should be a more natural proof method.

I did some attempts but failed. Let $n$, $m$ and $f$ be number of vertices,edges and faces respectively.
First of all, we know that each inner face is 3-circle, and the length of the exterior face is $n$. Let $f_3$ be number of $3$-face.
$$3f_3+n=2m$$
Then combine Euler's formula:
$$n-m+f=2$$
and
$$f_3+1=f.$$

But there is no expectation to get the value of $f_3$ or $m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$3f-3+n=2m$, $n-m+f=2$, $3n-3m+3f=6$, $3+2n-3m=6-2m$, $2n=3+m$, done.

Comment: Thanks! Haha, I made a calculation error and thought it couldn’t be derived.